# Getting HDMI No input on monitor, but monitor and computer and cable all work

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi

my daughter has a PC with a graphics card and a monitor. The monitor connects via HDMI cable. Her computer was working Saturday, but tonight she is getting HDMI 1 No Input on HDMI port 1 and HDMI 2 No Input when on HDMI port 2. The monitor only has two HDMI ports. We have tried the following steps:

1. We have tried a different HDMI cable between the monitor and the computer and checked both ports. No change.
2. We have tried plugging a different device (Nintendo Switch) into the monitor via the HDMI port. That worked.
3. We have checked both the original HDMI cable and the substitute HDMI cable between two different devices (TV and another gaming device). Both cables worked.
4. We have tried connecting the computer to the TV using both the original and the substitute HDMI cables. Both worked.
5. Of course, we have tried turning the devices off and on at various points to no avail.

It seems we have verified that the computer and its graphics card port, the cable itself, and the monitor and its two HDMI ports are all working. What could we be missing?

Comment: It might seem too obvious, but have you tried actually extending the desktop to the monitor? `Win key + P` then click on Extend or Second Screen Only.

Comment: The monitor is the only display for the desktop, and since the monitor is not displaying anything we cannot see anything to click on to extend the display. Also, since it is the only display for the desktop, we shouldn't have to extend the display.

Comment: Oh... I had it in my head that this was a laptop for some reason.